# Why is my Verilog code for 4x4 button matrix not scanning?

Tags: verilog, matrix

I have a problem with a module in Verilog where I need to scan a 4x4 button matrix. I don't get to scan each row 1 by one but the thing stick with the first row. Can you help me debug it? To me it looks logically correct.

The code is :

```
module keyboardScanner(input clk,input  [3:0] col, output reg [3:0] row,output reg [7:0] keyCode);
always @(posedge clk)begin
                row = 4'b1000;
                if(col != 4'b0000)begin
                        keyCode[0] = row[0];
                        keyCode[1] = row[1];
                        keyCode[2] = row[2];
                        keyCode[3] = row[3];
                        keyCode[4] = col[0];
                        keyCode[5] = col[1];
                        keyCode[6] = col[2];
                        keyCode[7] = col[3];
                end
                row = 4'b0100;
                if(col != 4'b0000)begin
                        keyCode[0] = row[0];
                        keyCode[1] = row[1];
                        keyCode[2] = row[2];
                        keyCode[3] = row[3];
                        keyCode[4] = col[0];
                        keyCode[5] = col[1];
                        keyCode[6] = col[2];
                        keyCode[7] = col[3];
                end
                row = 4'b0010;
                if(col != 4'b0000)begin
                        keyCode[0] = row[0];
                        keyCode[1] = row[1];
                        keyCode[2] = row[2];
                        keyCode[3] = row[3];
                        keyCode[4] = col[0];
                        keyCode[5] = col[1];
                        keyCode[6] = col[2];
                        keyCode[7] = col[3];
                end
                row = 4'b0001;
                if(col != 4'b0000)begin
                        keyCode[0] = row[0];
                        keyCode[1] = row[1];
                        keyCode[2] = row[2];
                        keyCode[3] = row[3];
                        keyCode[4] = col[0];
                        keyCode[5] = col[1];
                        keyCode[6] = col[2];
                        keyCode[7] = col[3];
                end
    end
endmodule // keyboardScanner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about what an `always` block does.

Every time there's a `posedge clk`, ALL of the statements inside the block are executed, and the LAST assignment to each signal is the one that applies. All of the other statements before that are effectively ignored.

Also, just for conciseness and readability, you don't need to assign each bit of a multi-bit field separately. You could write

```
keycode[3:0] <= row[3:0];
keycode[7:4] <= col[3:0];
```

or even just

```
keycode <= {col, row};
```

Finally, you'll also want to add a "strobe" or "valid" output to indicate when a key is being pressed (vs. no key pressed). Otherwise, you won't be able to detect the same key pressed twice in a row.

EDIT:

In order to do something sequentially in hardware, you need to set up a state machine. In this case, the `row` variable can be your state variable. For example:

```
module keyboardScanner (
  input            clk,
  input            reset,       /* additional input */
  input      [3:0] col,
  output reg [3:0] row,
  output reg [7:0] keyCode,
  output reg       keyValid     /* additional output */
);

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
      /* Reset all register variables.
       * Not strictly necessary for synthesis,
       * but the simulator will require it.
       */
      row <= 4'b1000;
      keyCode <= 8'b0;
      keyValid <= 0;
    end else begin
      /* If any column is active in the current row,
       * output the row and column pattern as a keyCode,
       * and assert keyValid. Pause the scanning as long
       * as the key is held down.
       */
      if (col != 4'b0000) begin
        keycode <= {col, row};
        keyValid <= 1;
      end else begin
        keyValid <= 0;
        /* Scan the matrix, one row per clock period
         */
        case (row)
          4'b1000: row <= 4'b0100;
          4'b0100: row <= 4'b0010;
          4'b0010: row <= 4'b0001;
          4'b0001: row <= 4'b1000;
          default: row <= 4'b1000;
        endcase
      end
    end
  end

endmodule // keyboardScanner
```

EDIT 2

The first version of the code that I posted had a couple of typos in it, plus an actual bug. As originally coded, if a key was held down, the logic would output a series of keyValid pulses as fast as the scanning could cycle. In order to fix this, the simplest thing to do is to pause the scanning when a key is down, as shown above.

The revised code still does not do any debouncing of the keypresses. There's a simple way to add that, too, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you suggest me a way to scan the 4x4 keyboard?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Correct me if wrong but I see that in 1 clock cycle you can't scan all rows and cols and output 1 keyCode. You need an FSM for that.

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj the code David shows doesn't scan all rows in one clock cycle. In each clock cycle the 'row' vector is changed by the case statement.

Comment: Thanks I understood that when I saw your code. Thanks for the explanation. I modified the fsm as my instructor wants it with 3 always blocks like the real fsm

Comment: Just a suggestion. `row` can assign with `row <= {row[0],row[3:1]};` instead of the case statement.

Comment: @Greg: Actually, that isn't a very good suggestion in this case, because it doesn't guarantee a "one-hot" pattern on `row` the way the `case` statement does. A better suggestion would be to use a 2-bit counter for the state variable and then decode `row` from that, because then there would be no illegal states.

Answer (score 2):

Here, no matter what is input `col`, the value of `row` is **always** `4'b0001`. Since `row` is driven from **multiple places**, at each posedge.

I think `row` must be driven from inside `if(col != 4'b....)` block.

Next is a general mistake. It is good practice to use non-blocking assignments inside `always` block. This may help in synthesizing the  design.  If you ignore the above guideline, then also you can still infer the correct synthesized logic, but the pre-synthesis simulation might not match the behavior of the synthesized circuit.

For more guidelines, refer to [this](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece447/s12/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:synth-verilog-cummins.pdf) and [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.149.3862&rep=rep1&type=pdf) link.

Comment: But my if statement makes sure that keycode is generated by the row where column is not 0. If I press a key at (0,0) then ythe only keycode generated will be 10001000

Comment: That's what I want to make clear. Either ALL the if's will be executed or none. The last if condition will win. So no matter what is your column number(except 0), the last if will decide the output. And ya, your row is OUTPUT here while col is input, so you'll only provide (,0) (no row input) as input, not (0,0). I posted my answer wrt. row variable, if that's wrong then we can't proceed to `keyCode`

Comment: The FSM of @Dave Tweed is a good example for this design.